# get Unique name and corresponding amount sum from a arraylist of maps

Tags: java

I am trying to iterate a arraylist.`List<Map<String, Object>> majorList=new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();`

Data Format would be

1. {"ledger": "A","basicAmt": 10,"excise": 2},
   {"ledger": "B","exciseAmt": 20,"grossAmt": 3},
    {"ledger": "A","basicAmt": 30,"excise": 5},
   {"ledger": "C","exciseAmt": 50,"grossAmt": 10},
   {"ledger": "B","basicAmt": 40,"excise": 8},

   And result required would be like:

   2. {"ledger": "A","basicAmt": 40,"excise": 7},
      {"ledger": "B","exciseAmt": 60,"grossAmt": 11},
      {"ledger": "C","basicAmt": 50,"excise": 10},

Comment: Is "ledger" the key of your map?

Comment: Glad that others seem to understand your question - I was really puzzled what your actual question is.

Comment: @underdog: yes ledger is the key.

Comment: your single key maps multiple values .... could you please elaborate what data structure is Object?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Explain your question.

Answer (score 0):

This will create a map of maps. The key in the top level is the ledger. The secondary map will have a key for each "type". A type will be created if it does not exist or added to an existing entry if it does. It finally displays the results at the end.

```
    List<Map<String, Object>> majorList = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();

    // setup
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("ledger", "A");
    map.put("basicAmt", 10);
    map.put("excise", 2);
    majorList.add(map);

    map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("ledger", "B");
    map.put("exciseAmt", 20);
    map.put("grossAmt", 3);
    majorList.add(map);

    map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("ledger", "A");
    map.put("basicAmt", 30);
    map.put("excise", 5);
    majorList.add(map);

    map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("ledger", "C");
    map.put("exciseAmt", 50);
    map.put("grossAmt", 10);
    majorList.add(map);

    map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("ledger", "B");
    map.put("basicAmt", 40);
    map.put("excise", 8);
    majorList.add(map);

    Map<String, Map<String, Object>> ledgers = new HashMap<>();

    // iterate through list
    for (Map<String, Object> m : majorList) {

        // get result map and create if does not exist
        String ledger = (String) m.get("ledger");
        Map<String, Object> ledgerMap = ledgers.get(ledger);
        if (ledgerMap == null) {
            ledgerMap = new HashMap<>();
            ledgers.put(ledger, ledgerMap);
        }

        // iterate through map for other keys
        for (Entry<String, Object> entry : m.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            // ignore ledger key
            if (!key.equals("ledger")) {
                // Add results
                Integer value = (Integer) entry.getValue();
                Integer existing = (Integer) ledgerMap.get(key);
                if (existing == null) {
                    ledgerMap.put(key, value);
                } else {
                    ledgerMap.put(key, existing + value);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // display results
    for (Entry<String, Map<String, Object>> entry : ledgers.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("Ledger: " + entry.getKey());
        for (Entry<String, Object> ledgerEntry : entry.getValue()
                .entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("  " + ledgerEntry.getKey() + ": "
                    + ledgerEntry.getValue());
        }
    }
```

Comment: With this code, i am getting all the excise amounts, but i would need sum of excise and sum of gross as per distinct ledger. as i have shown in my question

Comment: That is not in you question. Do you want to update it to what you want.

Comment: yes i want to iterate and add unique ledger names and sum of the  amount in a different list.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to populate a new Map and then add the values against the common key. After summing its better to have a `Map<String, Object>` as all the maps will be for unique ledger.

```
    Map<String, Map<String, Object>> sumMap = new HashMap<String, Map<String,Object>>();
    for (Map<String, Object> abc : majorList) {
        Map temp = sumMap.get((String) abc.get("ledger"));
        if (temp == null) {
            sumMap.put((String) abc.get("ledger"), abc);
        } else {
            for (Entry<String, Object> entry : abc.entrySet()) {
                if (!entry.getKey().equals("ledger")) {
                    temp.put(entry.getKey(),
                            (Integer) temp.get(entry.getKey())
                                    + (Integer) entry.getValue());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```